# Chrome is hiding some tabs if I have too many tabs open

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, tabs

I am not sure when it started.

Earlier behaviour: If they are too many tabs open, chrome will reduce the width of each tab to show all the tabs in the title bar.

Current behaviour: If they are too many tabs open, chrome hides some of them from the title bar.

I like the previous behaviour. How do I switch back to it?

Comment: Probably started happening the same time they implemented the circle with down arrow button near the minimize button in the top right of the window to access tabs and search for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.

1. Visit chrome://flags/#scrollable-tabstrip
2. Disable "Tab Scrolling"
3. Click on "Relaunch"

Comment: Nice! I've been looking for this for a long time. For me, the "default" on this setting was disabled tab scrolling. I enabled it, and my only complaint now is that I'd like my pinned tabs to always be visible.